# pandas dataframe group and sort by weekday

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have pandas DataFrame that includes `Day of Week` column.

```
df_weekday = df.groupby(['Day of Week']).sum()
df_weekday[['Spent', 'Clicks', 'Impressions']].plot(figsize=(16,6), subplots=True);
```

plot the DataFrame displays 'Day of Week' in alphabetical order: `'Friday', 'Monday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday' , 'Tuesday' , 'Thursday', 'Wednesday'`.

how can i sort and display df_weekday in proper weekday order `'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'`. ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [ordered catagorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#sorting-and-order) first:

```
cats = [ 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

df['Day of Week'] = df['Day of Week'].astype('category', categories=cats, ordered=True)
```

In `pandas 0.21.0+` use:

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=cats, ordered=True)
df['Day of Week'] = df['Day of Week'].astype(cat_type)
```

Or [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df_weekday = df.groupby(['Day of Week']).sum().reindex(cats)
```

Comment: i used 'reindex' solution and immediately worked, thank you.

Comment: Great solution jezrael!!  I love it!!

Answer (score 1):

A simple and robust solution is to **include day numbers in a multi-index** for sorting automatically.

```
birthdays = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.day_of_week,df['date'].dt.day_name()])['births'].sum()
birthdays = birthdays.droplevel(0,'index')
```

The full example on birthdays data

```
# group and sort by day-of-week

import pandas as pd
host = 'raw.github.com'
user = 'fivethirtyeight'
repo = 'data'
branch = 'master'
file = 'births/US_births_2000-2014_SSA.csv'
url = f'https://{host}/{user}/{repo}/{branch}/{file}'
df = pd.read_csv(url,sep=',',header=0)
df['date'] = df[['year','month','date_of_month']].astype(str).apply('-'.join,axis=1)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df[['date','births']]
df.head()

import seaborn as sns
birthdays = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.day_of_week,df['date'].dt.day_name()])['births'].sum()
birthdays = birthdays.droplevel(0,'index')
sns.barplot(data=birthdays.reset_index(),x='date',y='births')
```

[image]