# Reordering heatmap rows in Python using a custom categorical index order

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following dataframe

The index is days of the weeks
and the columns are numbers from 0 to 23 (hours of the day)
The cell values are counts

```
    0  1  2 ....
Mon 2  2  4
Tue 5  6  2
Wed 3  1  1
.
.
.
```

The dataframe is a result of

```
df.crosstab(df['DoW'],df['Hour'])
```

I tried using

```
hourdow.reindex(["Mon", "Tue", "Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat",'Sun'])
```

To get the Dataframe sorted but when i plot the graph is still end up with the index being sorted alphabetically on the heatmap. Is there anyway to reorder the rows?

Comment: See [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741400/pandas-dataframe-group-and-sort-by-weekday?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `df['DoW']` as a category first:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

days_order = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat",'Sun']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dow':np.random.choice(days_order,100),
                  'Hr':np.random.randint(0,4,100)})
df['Dow'] = pd.Categorical(df['Dow'], 
                           categories=days_order,
                           ordered=True)

sns.heatmap(pd.crosstab(df['Dow'],df['Hr']))
```

[image]

Comment: So I had to set the variable as categorical before creating a crosstab?

Comment: yes that's right.. or you can set it when doing the crosstab, for example, pd.crosstab(pd.Categorical(df['Dow']...),...)